# Xcode 5 - Archive added on project ever red

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I added one file in my project. But it ever appearing with font red (when Xcode not found).

I have tried delete  file from project and Clean project before and re-added. But without success.

Comment: Go into the project finder then delete it, Also delete it from trash. Now again add this file to project and make sure to check "Add files if Needed"(in Xcode 6). I think it will help you.

Comment: Yes I've done it, just the same result. I can still use this file normally. However my fear is the final version ends occurring problems.

Comment: :Goto Build Phase in the project setting & see if .m file exists in Compile Sources there or not?

Comment: On folder "database" is red. Out of folder is normal. Why?